# Posts critical of psychiatry deleted

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I'm finding that any posts which express any criticism of the psychiatric system (see [see this link](http://psychovoiceblog.wordpress.com)) get down voted and are eventually deleted no matter where they are found, no matter whether in chemistry discussing the drugs given to patients, health, or cognitive sciences.

I would like to know why this is.

I know a site specifically designed for mental health patients was meant to start, but never took off.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not the place to post criticism of anything, same way it's not the place to rant about things or share your personal experiences. For those things people can have personal blogs. Stack Exchange is network of Q&A sites: Questions and Answers. You ask a specific **question** about something, and get answers. Expressing criticism  is **not** asking a question. Bottom line: Stack Exchange is not the place for what you have in mind, sorry.

Comment: Is this affiliated with the church of scientology?

Comment: @Magisch Does it change the possible answers if your comment is answered yes or no?

Comment: This is not coming from a person affiliated with the church of Scientology, but from a person who occasionally likes to post questions closely or remotely related to psychiatry as someone familiar with psychiatric services. The response has always been deleted posts.

Comment: Related: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/168244)

Comment: Well, at least have the decency to not delete this post. The answers that were given were satisfactory and answered my question, and I think could be helpful to others. I hope the stack exchange community will have enough decency and respect for mental health suffers to preserve this post. If you do so thanks a lot, I think at least one post about psychiatry from someone who knows the suffering in the system should survive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are at least three different reasons you might be seeing this.

The first, and I would expect the largest, is that criticism is not a question. If I go to Travel.se and write a long post about how bad it is to go to other countries on holiday, it will end up closed and probably deleted not because of the opinion it expressed, but because an opinion is not a question. In other words a long post about how great it is to go to other countries on holiday should meet the same fate.

Now you may be able to shoehorn a question ("what can I do to minimize these terrible outcomes?", "how can I find a provider who won't do the awful things most providers do?", "how can I get trustworthy information about the side effects of something I've been prescribed?") into what is mostly a criticism of providers, their common practices, or particular medications. You may then run into the second reason, which is that people in a site about X are usually pretty invested in "X is good" and get angry when they read long screeds about how X is awful. They may then react with downvotes. Enough of those will remove your question from the front page. They may also feel "I can't answer this person's question, because I don't accept this person's premise, and in fact none of us can answer it so it should be closed." Enough of that and you can't have an answer added. We can argue that this reaction from the experts and enthusiasts in a site is wrong, but that won't change it. You could work on how to word your question so that it very clearly is a question, and you might leave out some of the background detail if it isn't actually needed to answer the question. There is no need to prove that you have a good reason to ask something.

The third is that you are imagining this effect because you only notice the disappearance of your own content or content you agree with, and you don't notice when the wildly pro-X questions disappear, perhaps because you don't have the rep to see deleted content from other people. There may be some of that. Perhaps for every ten things you post, 7 are poorly received because they are not questions, and 3 are poorly received because the people reading them are, well, human, while meanwhile out of 10 similar posts that are pro- the things you are anti-, 7 would disappear for not being questions, 1 would fall afoul of human emotion, and 2 would stay. You would end up observing a 2-0 "win" for being pro-X but that's not the underlying reality. Seeing the 7 deleted pro-X points would make it clearer to you.

These three scenarios combined probably explain what you are seeing.

Answer (score 5):

There's lots of people I personally know that have benefited from psychiatric care and are healthier and happier. But eh, that's anecdotal.

Having read through your posts - I get you're unhappy with the system, but

1. Its probably off topic for chemistry, because it has to do with health.
2. Modern medicine actually has a bunch of safeguards and we don't have rogue shrinks medicating, electroshocking and trepanning people willy nilly any more. Not saying you are accusing folks of doing that but modern medicine has come a long way.
3. People very often have a choice, and societal pressure can *prevent*
   people from getting help they need.
4. All the stuff linked there are opinions, not facts. Many sites dealing with subject material like this have a "back it up" rule. If you can give documented cases of these abuses - maybe your questions might be better recieved.

In a very real sense, I think the problem with these posts is they try to push an unsupported, potentially harmful point of view. Once again, if you can back these up with real, documented examples, these posts might be better recieved.

I'd also add, I'm a computer geek, and not part of the psychiatric system at this point of time. I can totally understand why these questions are closed though.